# Problem about the image and kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me with this problem on Linear Algebra.

Let $F$ be a field, $V$ and $W$ vector spaces over $F$. Prove that, if there exist a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ whose image and kernel have finite dimension, then $V$ has finite dimension.

Comment: Look at the Rank Nullity theorem.

Comment: @AritroPathak; Rank-Nullity is for $\dim V<\infty $

Comment: @Maths_Is_Fun. Yes, sorry. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_k\}$ be a basis of $\ker T$ and let $\{Tw_1,Tw_2,\ldots ,Tw_n\}$ form a basis of $W$.

Check that $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_k,w_1,w_2,\ldots ,w_n\}$ is a spanning set  of $V$ and hence $\dim V\le n+k\implies \dim V<\infty$

**EDIT**:

Let $x\in V$. If $Tx=0\implies x=\sum c_iv_i+\sum 0\cdot Tw_i$

If $Tx\neq 0\implies Tx=\sum d_iTw_i\implies x-\sum d_iw_i\in \ker T\implies x-\sum d_iw_i=\sum c_iv_i\implies x=\sum d_iw_i+\sum c_iv_i$

Comment: I understand that idea, but how can I check that the spanning is in fact V

Comment: @JOHNSANTANDER;Check that any element of V is a linear combination of the above set

Comment: sorry, I know that this is true. But I cant argue this sentence. could you give me a hint to prove that any v in V is a linear combination of the set?.

Comment: @JOHNSANTANDER;I edited it  Check now

Comment: Why downvotes?Explain please

Comment: Thaks a lot. Now that I see it it seems very easy, but when  I was trying things looked pretty difficult.

Comment: Happy to help !!

Answer (score 0):

One of possible formulations of [Rank–nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) is that $$\dim(V)=\dim(\operatorname{Ker} T)+\dim(\operatorname{Im} T).$$

So if you know (or can prove) this result, you are done.

Or, to be more precise, if you look at proof of this result, you can see that you get also that $V$ is finite dimensional if both $\operatorname{Ker} T$ and $\operatorname{Im} T)$ are. (This addition is mainly because - as pointed out in comments - rank-nullity theorem is usually formulated with the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional.)

You can probably find a few posts about this on this site. Quick search lead me, for example, to: [Proof that $\dim V = \dim \phi(V)+\dim \ker \phi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1077077).