# Why is this linear algebra proof correct? (dimension of the kernel and the image)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I was asked to prove the following theorem about vector spaces:

> Let $K$ be a field and let $V,W$ be vector spaces over $K$. If there is a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ are both finite dimensional, then $V$ is finite dimensional as well.

I tried to solve but I eventually gave up and looked up the solution. Turns out that I could only find variations of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472898/problem-about-the-image-and-kernel-of-a-linear-transformation) particular proof (a variation of the proof can be found on page 12 of [this](http://math.emory.edu/%7Elchen41/teaching/2020_Fall/Chapter_7.pdf) document). However, I'm having trouble understaing why it is correct, as the proof in the answer starts with the assumption that $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ has a basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$, and then a finite spanning set of $V$ is constructed from there. I think that makes sense, but what if $T$ is injective? Then we would have $\mathrm{Ker}(T)=\{0_{V}\}$, so that the only basis of $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ is the empty set, that has no vectors in it, so the proof wouldn't make sense, right?

I know this may be a silly question but I'm really having a bad time with this problem, any help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: If $\ker(T) = \{0\}$, then $T$ gives a bijection between $V$ and $\text{im}(T)$, which is assumed to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: The proof still works. Instead of checking $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_k,w_1,w_2,\ldots ,w_n\}$, you just check $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots ,w_n\}$ is a spanning set  of $V$.

Comment: It still works *without any modification*. When $T$ is injective, your list of basis vectors for the kernel just has length $0$. When $n=0$, the notation $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ can only be (and always is) interpreted as the empty set. Just like $\sum_{i=1}^0 a_i = 0$.

Comment: @A.M.Roche As a a remark on syntax, there is no need to append any indices to the vectors that constitute a basis of the kernel. It is far simpler syntactically to just consider a basis $B$ of the kernel. What I wanted to point out in my answer though is that the elegant way of establishing this classical result does not require *any explicit manipulation* of any bases whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks everyone! As @Christoph stated, it was the notation that confused me, but I get it now :)

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Your answer just skips manipulation of bases by hiding it in an unproven statement in parentheses: "(any subspace admits a supplementary by virtue of elementary vector space theory)".

Comment: @ΑΘΩ That's how I wanted to solve the problem (without expressing the basis explicitely), but I found no way of doing it with the little knowledge I have on linear algebra. From what I can understand from your answer, it seems that I need more definitions and theorems than I know to do that, but I do see your point! :)

Comment: @Christoph The description you give is not entirely appropriate. My answer presupposes a certain natural order in the introduction and expound of vector space theory, order in which existence and cardinal invariance of bases & extendibility of linearly independent subsets to bases come first, existence of supplementaries is derived as a corollary and rank-nullity issues come further on. I am assuming this order implicitly, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Christophe *(cont.)* for my aim is not to give a fully self-contained answer that would spell out absolutely every single justification of absolutely every single claim in vector space theory. Not from the very beginning, but only if the question poster showed further interest (case in which I would be glad to oblige, by presenting him/her with a more detailed view of the preliminary steps which are only tacitly referred to in the initial form of my answer).

Comment: @A.M.Roche I am glad you understand what I mean, and may I add that -- when speaking of the little knowledge you have -- it is not you who should be faulted for this but rather the order and structure of the expound of vector space theory you have been introduced to (presumably in a course or via a textbook). The natural order for this would include fundamental aspects about bases (as particular subsets), linearly independent subsets, extendability of the latter to the former, relations between bases of subspaces which decompose the ambient in the sense of direct sums *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @A.M.Roche *(cont.)* and so on. At any rate, feel free to ask questions if you would like to have more details regarding my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the same proof works when  $ker(T)=\{0_V\}$. Let $\{Tw_1,Tw_2,..,Tw_k\}$ be  a basis for the image of $T$. Take any $x \in V$. Then $Tx$ is a linear combination of the basis elements, say $Tx=\sum c_iTw_i$. But then $T(x-\sum a_iw_i)=0$ so $x=\sum a_iw_i$ We have proved that $V$ is spanned by $w_1,w_2,...,w_k$ so $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider an arbitrary (not necessarily commutative) field $K$, two left $K$-vector spaces $V$ and $V'$ and a $K$-linear map $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathit{K}-\mathbf{Mod}}}(V, V')$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}f$ and $\mathrm{Im}f$ are both finite dimensional. Fix an arbitrary *supplementary* subspace $U$ of the kernel $\mathrm{Ker}f$ in $V$ (any subspace admits a supplementary by virtue of elementary vector space theory). It is easy to show that the linear map $g\colon={}_{\mathrm{Im}f|}f_{|U}\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathit{K}-\mathbf{Mod}}}(U, {\mathrm{Im}f})$ obtained by restricting $f$ is an *isomorphism*, whence $\mathrm{dim}_KU=\mathrm{dim}_K\mathrm{Im}f=\mathrm{rk}_K f$. Indeed, we have $\mathrm{Ker}g=\mathrm{Ker}f \cap U=\{0_V\}$, meaning that $g$ is injective and $\mathrm{Im}f=f\left[U+\mathrm{Ker}f\right]=f[U]+f[\mathrm{Ker}f]=f[U]=g[U]=\mathrm{Im}g$, meaning that $g$ is also surjective.

As $U$ and the kernel are supplementary, it follows that $\mathrm{dim}_K V=\mathrm{dim}_K \mathrm{Ker}f+\mathrm{dim}_K U$. Since the sum of two finite cardinals (which are nothing else than natural numbers in the axiomatic system I adhere to) is also finite, we gather that $\mathrm{dim}_K V \in \mathbb{N}$, in other words $V$ is finite dimensional.

The above argument is actually part of the standard proof of the notorious *rank-nullity* relation, valid for *any* vector space morphism $h \colon V \to V'$ and according to which $\mathrm{dim}_K V=\mathrm{dim}_K \mathrm{Ker}h+\mathrm{dim}_K \mathrm{Im}h$.

Comment: There's really no point in using the notation $f\in \operatorname{Hom}_{K-\text{Mod}}(V,V')$ instead of $f\colon V\to V'$ when explaining something to a student struggling with linear algebra.

Comment: @Christoph But there is. The student -- as much of a neophyte he might happen to be -- has sufficient explanation furnished in natural language, by syntagms such as *linear map* et al. What effect the exposure to somewhat more abstract notation might have on him we can only surmise, but there is no reason to shy away from it. If he does not find his curiosity piqued by it, no matter. If he does, he is also free to ask and I will gladly answer.